# Pulling Swagger API with python

Tags: python, swagger

Can someone explain how I can pull this API info with python or point me in the right direction?

On the swagger documentation page for the API I am trying to access, I go to the header authentication section; paste in the API key, and am returned with a 'Base XXXXXXXXXXXX" key. Which I learned is an encoded base64 key. Then I paste the Basic key into the API key input filed in another section (See screenshot) and am successful in pulling the API information.

However, I cannot figure out how to pull that information with python requests or postman. When I google "Pulling API with basic API key" It says I need a username and password.

Any help would be appreciated. My apologize for the noob question [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCwfm.png)

[image: Screen shots of API documentation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```py
from hashlib import new
from unicodedata import name
from urllib import response
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'URL'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxx'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers )

data = r.json()
```